# Не работает список в python

Tags: python

Я хотел написать программу из книги, которая должна была бы составлять список котов, но почему-то *pycharm* указывает, что переменная *CatNames* не существет, хотя я указывал его в начале кода как пустой список. Я указал строку кода где *pycharm* показывает ошибку ******* звездочками.

```
catNames=['']
while True:
    print('Enter the name of cat '+ str((len(catNames))+1) + ' Or enter Nothing to stop')
    name=input()
    if name=='':
        break
    catNames=CatNames+['name']     *************
    print('The cat names are:')
    print(CatNames)
```

Comment: в разном регистре переменные

Comment: `catNames` и `CatNames` - разные переменные.

Answer (score 3):

`catNames` существует, а `CatNames` нет.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте пустой список - `cat_names = []`, а цикле добавляйте в него элементы-строки, которые пользователь вводит с клавиатуры: `cat_names.append(name)`. В итоге получится что-то подобное:

```
cat_names = []
while True:
    name = input('Enter the name of cat or enter Nothing to stop')
    if not name:
        break
    print(f'The cat names are: {name}')
    cat_names.append(name)
    
print(cat_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Укажите перед строкой которая вызывает ошибку:

```
CatNames = catNames
```

ИЛИ
Лучше заменить CatNames на catNames